# How to embed a GWT widget in a hyperlink?

Tags: gwt, hyperlink

I need to implement the following method:

```
public static Widget embedInHyperlink(String href, Widget content);
```

The method needs to create a widget, which is rendered as `<a href="...">[content]</a>` on the web site.

Content can be a complex widget which contains images text and other widgets.

My first solution was to create a `FocusPanel` and add an `ClickHandler`, but then users can not [Ctrl]-Click the widget to open it in an new browser tab. Right-Click and "Open in new Tab" or "Save as.." is also not possible, when my content widget is not embedded in a hyperlink.

Comment: I think it is already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128178/gwt-how-to-embed-widgets-in-anchor-with-uibinder
Specifically look at the Anchor-based answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AnchorPanel extends SimplePanel {

    public AnchorPanel(IsWidget content, String href, String target) {
        super(DOM.createAnchor());
        getElement().setAttribute("href", href);
        getElement().setAttribute("target", target);
        add(content);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use or extend the [HTML](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html) widget to construct your elements. If you can avoid using child widgets, you will be better off, as widgets are typically not thoroughly tested to work correctly when wrapped by a href.  If you must use child widgets you can use a [HTMLPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html) instead.

Comment: I dont get it. How does HTMLPanel help me create a hyperlink around my existing widgets?

Comment: Pass an html snippet that includes the hyperlink with a unique ID to  the HtmlPanel constructor, then attach your widget using the add(widget,id) method.